# LINQ Join method odd syntax of a colleague, question

Tags: linq-to-entities

A colleague (that left the company) has written the following join:

```
var result = outer
  .Join(inner, o => new { o.BaseId }, i => new { i.BaseId }, (outer, i) => new { outer,i })
  .Select(x => ...);
  {
```

I find the on-statement strange:

```
o => new { o.BaseId }, i => new { i.BaseId }
```

I would have done it like this

```
o => o.BaseId, i => i.BaseId
```

Is there a difference?

Comment: The only difference is on first approach he was generating an object for each keySelector, on second you are using primitives. See more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join)

Comment: yes, this is what I meant. Both indicate the key criterion. Does it matter if Object or Primitive?

Comment: On that case no, as was used a single field on keySelectors. This object approach is more useful when you have more than one field.

Comment: If this was for LINQ to Databases, then there would be no difference, since the LINQ is translated to a database query language (commonly SQL). If this is for LINQ to objects, then not creating the objects is better (and what I would do), but some programmers like to put in unnecessary braces in anticipation of possible future maintenance, and this might be something like that.